# Installing Ubuntu over a Windows 10 partitioned disk

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu on a DELL laptop that has two partitions, C for system files and F for my stuff.

Do I need to merge the partitions first so that there is only one partition to install onto, or will the Ubuntu install take care of it?

Thanks.

Comment: The installer gives you the option to use the whole disk, and will do the partitioning for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Please understand the suggestion given in the first comment will result in total data loss in that drive. Perhaps better to backup your "stuff" first just to be safe, then learn a few basic things about partitions and dual-booting - the duplicate above is a good start - before actually attempt it.